# Why is a photon's energy described by $E^2=(pc)^2$ if a photon field is described by $A^\mu$?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, photons, field-theory, maxwell-equations

We can use [Einstein's famous energy equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence):
$$E^2=(mc^2)^2+(pc)^2 \tag{1}$$

To find the relativistic energy.
I can turn this into quantum mechanics and I'll have the [Klein-Gordon Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation):

$$\partial^2 \psi - m^2 \psi = 0 \tag{2}$$

Everything was fine until I found that a photon field is $A^\mu$ and is not described by the [Klein-Gorden equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation), but rather by [Maxwell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_formulation_of_classical_electromagnetism):

$$\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu} = 0\tag{3}$$

(For a free electromagnetic field).

What makes us believe you can use $(1)$ to find the energy of a photon if its wave isn't even described by anything that stems from it, i.e Klein-Gordon Equation $(2)$ or [Dirac's Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation)?

---

Note: I know that [Maxwell's Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_formulation_of_classical_electromagnetism) can be turned into 4 sets of [Klein-Gordon Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation) with $m=0$ using the [Lorenz Gauge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_gauge_condition), but I don't know if this has anything to do with it. I've always thought it was a coincidence by our choice of [Gauge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing).

Comment: This describes the wavefunction of a photon, the point elementary particle,https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0604169 .  It is the quantized maxwell equation, thus the continuity. Remember the wave in a wave function s a **probability wave**,

Comment: I didn't quite get you. By "This" you mean Klein-Gordon Equation?

Comment: $F\sim\partial A$, so Maxwell's equations are like $\partial^2 A=0$, with extra bells

Comment: Hint: (1) is $k^2=0$. Rewrite (3) as $\square A^\nu=0$ in the Lorentz gauge $\partial_\mu A^\mu=0$, so Fourier-transforming $k^2\widetilde{A}^\nu=0$.

Comment: @Habouz  No. read the link. I mean the Maxwell equation used with differential operators on wavefunctions

Comment: "What makes us believe you can use (1) to find the energy of a photon?" The answer is that many experimental results test this and confirm that it works. Physics is not math.

Comment: There got to be an explanation though